# For each variable type, divide all rows with one reference row

Tags: r

```
n = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",4),rep("C",3))
s = 1:10 
b = 5:14
c = 20:29
df = data.frame(n, s, b, c)
```

[image]

I want each first row, for each type of the variable *n* (A, B, C), to be the reference row. And I would like to divide each row, in each category of *n* to be divided by the reference row (including the reference row itself). I think I have to use some apply function, but I'm not sure how to attack this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), group by 'n', loop through the other columns, divide by the reference row (first row - `x[1]`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x/x[1]) , n]
```

and if needed it can be assigned (`:=`) back to the columns of interest

```
setDT(df)[, (2:ncol(df)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x/x[1]) , n]
```

---

If we wanted the 'n2' to be untouched, then specify the columns in `.SDcols`

```
nm1 <- setdiff(names(df), c("n", "n2"))
setDT(df)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x/x[1]) , n, .SDcols = nm1]
```

---

Or another option is `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %?%
     group_by(n) %>%
     mutate_each(funs(./.[1]), setdiff(names(.), "n2"))
```

Comment: That is brilliant! I have to learn data tables! Would it also be possible if I had a non numerical column *n2* that I would want left untouched?

Answer (score 2):

With `base R` :

```
df[-1] <- as.data.frame(sapply(df[-1], function(col) ave(col, df$n, FUN=function(x) x / x[1])))
df
   n     s        b        c
1  A 1.000 1.000000 1.000000
2  A 2.000 1.200000 1.050000
3  A 3.000 1.400000 1.100000
4  B 1.000 1.000000 1.000000
5  B 1.250 1.125000 1.043478
6  B 1.500 1.250000 1.086957
7  B 1.750 1.375000 1.130435
8  C 1.000 1.000000 1.000000
9  C 1.125 1.083333 1.037037
10 C 1.250 1.166667 1.074074
```

Comment: 2 mins late. Maybe you should also include `data.frame(df[c(1:2)], sapply(df[-c(1,2)], function(i) ave(i, df$n, FUN = function(j)j/j[1])))` to make it more complete

Comment: I saw, thank you for helping, though! Much appreciated!