# Convert the value of each row in a particular column into a percentage of the value of a particular row in that particular column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame consisting of data from financial statements (e.g. Income Statement, Balance Sheet, Cash Flow Statement), with each row referring to a financial statement entry (e.g. revenue, profits) and with each column referring to a particular year.

An example of the data would be the following:

```
variable <- c("Revenue", "Cost of Goods Sold", "Gross Profit", "SG&A", "Operating Income", "Interest Expense", 
          "Pretax Income", "Income Tax", "Net Income")
year_2014 <- c(6500, 3012, 3488, 1231, 2257, 231, 2026, 462, 1564)
year_2015 <- c(3250, 1323, 1927, 912, 1015, 109, 906, 209, 697)
year_2016 <- c(4965, 2723, 2242, 1159, 1083, 106, 977, 187, 790)
df <- data.frame(variable, year_2014, year_2015, year_2016)
```

I would like to common sized the financial statement, where I divide every single row against the revenue. For example, in year 2014, Net Income of 1564/Revenue of 6500 * 100. Income tax of 462/Revenue of 6500 * 100 and so on.

The end result which I am looking for looks something like this:
[image: Common Sized Income Statement]

I have tried multiple ways to solve the problem but it all did not work:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
    mutate(percentage = year_2014/filter(select(year_2014), variable == "Revenue")
```

This [source](https://github.com/STAT545-UBC/Discussion/issues/134) indicated that I cannot filter within mutate.

I tried using subsetting notation to get the "Revenue" row for the subsequent division steps, but it failed:

```
df <- df %>%
    mutate(percentage = year_2014/variable["Revenue"])
```

I have searched Stackoverflow as well, but am unable to find an answer. The "closest" answer I got was this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224162/divide-all-rows-by-a-reference-row-by-group?rq=1) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41740171/for-each-variable-type-divide-all-rows-with-one-reference-row). However, those posts are different as their datasets are in a long format (in contrast to wide format like mine), their datasets consists of groups (I have nothing to "group_by"), and I need to hardcode the specific row I am making reference to.

Much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can try `dplyr::mutate_at`. Moreover, if `Revenue` is not expected to be the 1st row, then a generic solution can be as:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("year")), 
                  funs(100*./.[which(variable == "Revenue")])) %>%
  as.data.frame()


#             variable year_2014 year_2015 year_2016
# 1            Revenue    100.00    100.00    100.00
# 2 Cost of Goods Sold     46.34     40.71     54.84
# 3       Gross Profit     53.66     59.29     45.16
# 4               SG&A     18.94     28.06     23.34
# 5   Operating Income     34.72     31.23     21.81
# 6   Interest Expense      3.55      3.35      2.13
# 7      Pretax Income     31.17     27.88     19.68
# 8         Income Tax      7.11      6.43      3.77
# 9         Net Income     24.06     21.45     15.91
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Just curious, why is it I am unable to use "select" and have to use "vars" in your answer above? Doesn't "funs" have to take a summarizing function? I'm not familiar with mutate_at. Does it create multiple columns? Thanks again!

Comment: What is the purpose of `as.data.frame` at the end? The output is a `data.frame` even otherwise.

Comment: @DTYK The 2nd argument of `mutate_at` accepts list of `column` names on which `.funs` will be applied. In your case 3 columns (`year_2014, year_2015, year_2016`) is selected. Now the `funs` is applied on all the 3 columns one by one.

Comment: @DTYK, The `vars` function is an alternate to the `select` operation in the sense that it lets you select variables within  `mutate` or `summarize` operations directly without an explicit need for the `select` step. If you want to perform the variable selection separately, you only have to use `starts_with` within the `select` operation. `select(starts_with("year"))`

Comment: @DeepakRajendran You are correct. `as.data.frame` is not needed as such. Its more of my habit to avoid `multi-line` headers of `tibble`.

Comment: @MKR, Understood. ^_^